# For a shared git repo served over SSH and HTTPS, how to control access for both protocols?

Tags: git, webdav

I'm using `hooks/update` to control who may update particular refs in a shared repository. This works great for SSH, but I recently discovered (with git-1.6.4.2, at least) this hook does not influence WebDAV pushes, *i.e.*, any user may update any branch.

Yes, I could add `Require group ...` directives as in [8 ways to share your git repository](http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/#apachehttp) along with separate group files, but I'd like to avoid having to maintain parallel authorization configs!

Another alternative is rewriting the `hooks/update`, but that seems a waste given that it's already working for SSH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should understand that for Git (currently) HTTPS is a "dumb" protocol, i.e. whole exchange goes without involving git on server at all, including running hooks; it is only web server (with WebDAV for HTTPS push) that is involved.

You should however take a look at repository access management tools, such as **Gitosis** (in Python, using setuptools), or new **Gitolite** (in Perl, simpler), or **repo** tool from the Google's Android project, or something else.  Perhaps they would offer centralized access management.